# How to find out Mirror Resiliency level is 2-way or 3-way in Storage Spaces

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

How to find the Mirror Resiliency level for Virtual Disks in Storage Spaces using Powershell?

```
eg. 2-way mirror or 3-way mirror
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Get-VirtualDisk | Ft FriendlyName, NumberOfDataCopies

For three-way mirror space, NumberofDataCopies is '3'.
For two-way mirror space, NumberofDataCopies is '2'.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell commandlet to do that is `Get-ResiliencySetting`.

For Example, just one object:

```
PS C:\>Get-ResiliencySetting -UniqueId "{deadbeef-ca00-11e1-9350-00155db7aa01}:1"
```

Comment: Isn't _Get-ResiliencySetting_ is only showing the resiliency levels that are available when creating virtual disks, and not what is already configured?

[Get-ResiliencySetting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-resiliencysetting?view=windowsserver2019-ps#:~:text=The%20Get%2DResiliencySetting%20cmdlet%20gets,Mirror%2C%20and%20Parity%20resiliency%20settings)

Comment: I am so sorry, I somehow misread the question. The command for getting the *actual* resilency setting (not the avaible ones) for a storage pool is `Get-StoragePool | ft FriendlyName ,ResiliencySettingNameDefault`.

Comment: Nope that is also not correct. It doesn't show whether it is 2-way mirror or 3-way mirror.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM2ME.png

Comment: There is no (buitliin) way to check if 2- oder 3-way parity is active on a volume.